# How to implement search in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django 1.9 when your in the admin are and click either groups or user there is a search field. I'd like to have that same search field in my most area to search for particular post. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [ModelAdmin.search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields).

You need to specify `search_fields` for your admin class:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('excerpt', 'copy', )
```

Comment: If you'd like to search on a foreign key field, don't forget the double underscore separation. For instance, `foreignKey__foreignField`